# FTP Not Connected - Can't input user credentials

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, ftp

I'm trying to download a file from a Linux server via FTP from Windows command line. I've successfully downloaded the file with FileZilla (same server, same file), but I want to do it in `cmd.exe`.

I've tried two things:

```
$ ftp 10.58.83.2  
ftp> cd /home  
Not connected.  
ftp>  


$ ftp  
ftp> open 10.58.83.2  
ftp> cd /home  
Not connected.  
ftp>
```

Why am I not prompted to enter user creds?

== EDIT ==
I tried to specify the port

```
$ ftp
ftp> open 10.58.83.2 22
Connected to 10.58.83.2.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
<Waits for a minute or so>
Connection closed by remote host.
ftp>
```

After it says I'm connected it just waits a minute and then closes the connection. I have succeeded with FileZilla so it should be possible, right?

Comment: The server is either using a different port for ftp or you have the wrong address.

Comment: ftp is port `21`, not `22`.

Comment: I can connect with FileZilla on port 22. Not on port 21 - it says Connection refused. But when I connect on port 22 with FileZilla it uses SFTP.

Comment: Filezilla supports sftp - it's actually file transfer over ssh, and doesn't require an ftp server. There's probably something wrong or not running with your FTP server - most linux distrobutions require that you specifically install and configure a ftp server in order to use ftp.

Comment: BTW the command to connect to a ssh server is called "sftp" - there's a version for windows called PSFTP if you want a cli sftp program.

Comment: I you have the capability of using SFTP, then use SFTP unless you have a very specific and compelling reason for using legacy FTP as FTP is insecure and everything is transmitted in plain text.  If you are getting connection refused, then there is no FTP daemon listening (or it's listening on another port, but option 1 is more likely).

Answer (score 0):

try using ftp command: `user your_ftp_user` then password after enter(i use it that way with script file, password in new line), or `user your_ftp_user thats_user_password` but I haven't tried password in same line as user.

and to connect to specific port you might have to use ftp command `open address port` as you did, it won't work directly using `ftp address:port` - didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the EXACT same experience trying to ftp to an as400.  Turns out the ftp job wasn't running on the server.  Just has to start it.